# Is there a minimalized example of how to use Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) in OpenGL ES 1.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm having a really hard time finding beginner-friendly resources about using Vertex Buffer Objects.

The closest thing I came across was [this tutorial](http://playcontrol.net/ewing/jibberjabber/opengl_vertex_buffer_object.html), but it deals with a 3D rotating cube and also doesn't do any subsequent color modification after the VBO has been created.

Maybe someone knows an even better tutorial which reduces the complexity to the simplest base line possible to understand how VBOs work.

My boss wants me to implement VBOs for a simulation where we have a grid of rectangles which is colorized about 30 times per second. Right now my logic simply creates one rectangle after another and issues a glDrawArrays call, which is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best tutorial I've found online about OpenGL ES: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html

You also have the Golden Book if necessary: [http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0321502795/khongrou-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321502795) (10 pages to read in chapter 6 to get an introduction on VBOs)

(and what about giving up OpenGL ES 1.1 to OpenGL ES 2.0 ?)